# Snap to Snapcraft publication error Exec, Type

Tags: flutter, snapcraft, snap

I am getting the followings errors when I try to publish the snap:

```
Could not find 'Exec=' in desktop file lint-snap-v2_desktop_file (exec, name.desktop)
Could not find 'Type=Application' in desktop file lint-snap-v2_desktop_file (type, name.desktop)
```

But in the app.desktop the commands are specified:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.2
Name=name
Comment=description
Exec=exec-name
Icon=${SNAP}/meta/gui/name.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue!

So I checked the desktop file again and figured out there were blank spaces on each begin of line! If you've got still the problem check for blank lines. :)
After removing the spaces it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's it, worked after deleting the blank spaces before the lines.